# Oracle table function parameter

Tags: sql, oracle

I've created a pipelined table funcion:

> tabfunc_cube_tab(i_cube_name VARCHAR2)

i_cube_name is the name of a TABLE.
When you perform:

```
select *
from table(tabfunc_cube_tab('CB_225'));
```

you got the records of the table 'CB_225'.

I have alos a table with all possible table names that you can use as input of the tabfunc_cube_tab.

I performed this query:

```
 select a.cube_ora_table_name,b.* 
 from control.ct_cube_olap_relation a,
 table(tabfunc_cube_tab(a.cube_ora_table_name)) b;
```

My question is.. why is it working? A.CUBE_ORA_TABLE_NAME is a field of the first table and it is in the same level of the tabfunc function...
Someone can explain me? Is something releated to pipelinede table funcions (I wasn't able to create an example with a normal function that work in the same thing).

Thanks. Marco

Comment: Don't understand your question...

Comment: It's just the nature of a Oracle's pipelined functions.  If you were to switch the order of the tables it wouldn't work. [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/tuning.htm#i52932)  Key point: Instead of waiting until it has buffered a complete result set of all rows, a pipelined table function returns rows one at a time, using PIPE_ROW.